# more than one kendo autocomplete in a razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, kendo-ui, partial-views

i want use kendo autocomplete in Partial View , and i have many Of that in one view
therefore i must get parameter dynamically , is there any way that i can get element id in Data fanction ? i  $(this).val()  but it dose not work :( , what dose i should use?
please help me :(
 tihs is my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
.Name("Employee" + (string)Session["fileid"]) 
.Placeholder("Employee Name ...")
.Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
.DataSource(source =>
{
    source.Read(read =>
                 {
        read.Action(
                        "GetEmployeeName",
                         "Proceeds")
                         .Data(
                      "function onAdditionalData() {return { text:$(this).val() };}");
          })
                     .ServerFiltering(true);
})
.Events(e => { e.Open("onOpen");})
.Animation(true)
)
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is happening here. The value is automatically send to the server. Why would you need to send it through the Data function?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply ,I have many AutoComplete controls on my view, and I want to write just ONE *read.Action("GetCountries", "Proceeds").Data("onAdditionalData")* function for all of them and I must get the ID of each selected AutoComplete control in this function (to get the user inputted value and pass it to the specified action). The code is as follow:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
 .Name("Employee" + (string)Session["fileid"]) 
 .Placeholder("Employee Name ...")
 .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
 .DataSource(source =>
  {
    source.Read(read =>
                 {
         read.Action(
                    "GetEmployeeName",
                     "Proceeds")
                     .Data("onAdditionalData");
      })
         .ServerFiltering(true);
  })
  .Animation(true)
 )

function onAdditionalData() {
var id = this.element.attr('id');//This line is my problem, because it does not
//work and I can not get the ID of the currently focused AutoComplete control.
id = '#' + id;
return {    text: $(id).val() };
}
```

This is the action part:

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GetEmployeeName(string text)
    {
    return Json(/*SOMEVALUES*/, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

if i dont use .Data("onAdditionalData") it send null as parameter to action

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that has worked for me...

```
function onAdditionalData(e) {
    return { text: e.filter.filters[0].value };
}
```

Additionally, you can change the controller action name to add the ID of the field...

```
read.Action("MyAction#" + id, "MyController").Data("onAdditionalData");
```

and access the attribs that way, allowing for you to set data parameters and use them in the event:

```
function onAdditionalData(e) {
    var filterValue = e.filter.filters[0].value;
    var field = $(this.url.substring(this.url.indexOf('#')));
    return {
        text: filterValue,
        extradata1: field.data("extradata1"),
        extradata2: field.data("extradata2")
    };
}
```

The hash tag in the URL will be removed by the browser during the GET to the server.

I use this method to pass list source enums and various other parameters to create a very flexible AJAX interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the value of the control and don't care about the control itself you can do this...

```
 function onAdditionalData(e) {
    return { text: e.filter.filters[0].value };
  }
```